# How can I get a variable from a string?

Tags: python

Say I have a variable named `variable` and make it equal to a string that I would like to print out. Now, let’s say I only have a string version of the variable name. How could I print what the variable is? Here’s what I mean:

```
variable = "Hello!"
string = "variable"
```

How could I make it print "Hello" from the string?

Comment: so you want print the variable name from its value?

Comment: I have to say that I find the question text no less confusing than the title :(

Comment: Can you please show an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: yes! @mkrieger1, I’ll edit my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To take your example.

```
variable = 'variable'
```

So, we just have now the value of variable, which is 'variable'.

But, if we type

```
globals()['variable']
```

OUTPUT

[image]

It's exactly as if you had typed variable

Comment: you’re literally awesome, thank you so much. sincerest apologies for being so unclear